# libGL error: MESA-LOADER failed to open iris and swrast VSCode - Ubuntu 22

Tags: drivers, python

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  112
  Current serial number in output stream:  113
```

I'm new in coding, I'm trying to code my first snake game in python. I had then to install `pygame`. Unfortunately when I run my code it gives me this error, can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110384/libgl-error-mesa-loader-failed-to-open-iris and, BTW, this is the site where you should post programming question. AU is Ubuntu, the OS, centered.

Comment: so should I post it in stackoverflow? because from what I understood it is also an Ubuntu problem... @ChanganAuto

Comment: Generic programming questions should be there indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case of `python-vlc` and `pygame`, it is anaconda3/miniconda3's problem. I have two `miniconda3` environments, one is old, one is new. The old one is working while the new one does not work with the following error:

```
xuancong@mx:~/projects/*$ ./miniconda3/bin/python -i debug.py 
>>> libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  44
```

So I used `lsof -p <PID>` to poke all dynamic libraries that is used. It turns out that the problem lies in `miniconda3/lib/libffi*.so`.
The old conda environment (working) has:

```
67214 Jul  7  2020 libffi.a
   15 Apr 28  2022 libffi.so -> libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Apr 28  2022 libffi.so.6 -> libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Apr 28  2022 libffi.so.7 -> libffi.so.7.1.0
50664 Jul  7  2020 libffi.so.7.1.0
```

while the new conda environment (not working) has:

```
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.7.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.8.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
 97758 May 10  2023 libffi.a
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.so.7 -> libffi.so.8.1.2
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.so.8 -> libffi.so.8.1.2
 72144 May 10  2023 libffi.so.8.1.2
```

The root cause of this error turns out to be that `libffi.so.8` is not downward compatible with `libffi.so.7`, so that you cannot simply soft-link all versions of `libffi.so` to `libffi.so.8`. So all I did was to copy over `libffi.so.7.1.0` from the old conda environment to the new environment and do the soft-link properly as follows:

```
   15 Jan 31 17:03 libffi.7.so -> libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Jan 31 09:48 libffi.8.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
97758 May 10  2023 libffi.a
   15 Jan 31 17:09 libffi.so -> libffi.so.8
   15 Jan 31 17:17 libffi.so.7 -> libffi.so.7.1.0
50664 Jan 31 17:02 libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Jan 31 09:48 libffi.so.8 -> libffi.so.8.1.2
72144 May 10  2023 libffi.so.8.1.2
```

And then everything runs correctly. Take note that you can still link the default `libffi.so` to the highest version, i.e., `libffi.so -> libffi.so.8`, it will still work. This is because the runtime dynamic library loader will try to load the closest-and-no-lower version of the library.